# Связать две модели и сохранить

Tags: django

Здравствуйте!

Есть модели "Competion" и "Team":

```
models.py 

class Competition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Team(models.Model):
    myteam_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Команды (экземпляры team1, team2 и т.п.) могут принимать участие в конкурсах (экземпляры competition1, competition2 и т.д.).

Каким образом можно хранить информацию об этих связях? Полагаю, необходима промежуточная модель, например, Membership, как в примере https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/db/models.html#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships? Или есть какие-либо другие способы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас очевидно, что каждая команда может принимать участие во многих соревнованиях, т.е. связь many-to-many. Все правильно
competitions = models.ManyToManyField(Competition)

Если вам нужно хранить доп. информацию то делается через дополнительную модель Membership как в документации

Comment: Да, так и сделал. К тому же связь при использовании связи many-to-many django автоматически создает дополнительную таблицу.